# Invalid Variance in val use - error: contravariant type U occurs in covariant position

Tags: scala, covariance, variance, contravariance

I have a question about Scala variances.

The code below is valid code, which passes compile.

```
// <Code A> 
// VALID (COMPILE PASS!)
class A[+T, -U](t: T, u: U)
```

But the code below is not valid, which use `val` and doesn't pass compile.

```
// <Code B>
// INVALID (COMPILE ERROR)
class A[+T, -U](val t: T, val u: U)
```

The error message is the following.

```
error: contravariant type U occurs in covariant position in type => U of value u
class A[+T, -U](val t: T, val u: U)
                                 ^
```

I wonder why `<Code A>` is valid and `<Code B>` isn't valid. Could someone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `U` to be contravariant (that's what `-U` means).  Another way of thinking about contravariance is that it's an "input type".  ie. The type can be used as a parameter for methods, but not as a return value.

By declaring it as a val, it's now accessible outside of the class as an "output value".  This breaks the rule of contravariance.

If you wish to make `U` a val, you must either make it covariant (`+U`) if possible, or if you need it to be an input as well it must be made invariant.